# How can I realize a CSS layout with a fixed sidebar and scrollable content?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'd like to create such a layout:

[image: Prototype of what I'd like to achieve]

**Red**: Fixed sidebar that expands to the right when opened.

**Blue**: Content, scrollable and **should move to the right** when the sidebar expands

Now, when I try to code this using the float attribute, the sidebar scrolls too. How can I create a fixed sidebar that doesn't scroll? The content on the right however should still scroll.

```
.sidebar, .content {
    float: left;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6tMFm/)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: did you see my updated answer? http://jsfiddle.net/6tMFm/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone, but this is [the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/6tMFm/24/) I was looking for:

```
.content {
    background-color: #4c8ae8;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.actual-content {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="actual-content">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

No additional JS is required and it's dynamic (e.g. when the width of the sidebar changes)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Set the side bar `position:fixed`

http://jsfiddle.net/6tMFm/3/

Comment: Thanks, I tried this too. But the blue content has to move to the right when it expands.

Comment: to move right panel you'll need **to move it** for example with margin-left or position:absolute and left property. Since left bar is fixed it does not affects right panel.

Comment: This would be great if it worked with fluid width content.

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/6tMFm/28/

CSS

```
.sidebar {
    background-color: #f12f2f;
    width: 50px;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}

.sidebar.extended {
    width: 100px;

}

.content {
    background-color: #4c8ae8;
    width: 200px;
    left:65px;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    padding:10px;
}
```

.sidebar, .content {

```
height: 1000px;
width:auto;
float:left;
position:absolute;
right:0;
```

}

```
.clearBoth {
    clear: both;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="sidebar">Fixed Side</div>
<div class="content">loremipsum<br/><br/>lorem ipsum<br/><Br/>loremipsum<br/><br/>lorem ipsum<br/><Br/>loremipsum<br/><br/>lorem ipsum<br/><Br/>loremipsum<br/><br/>lorem ipsum<br/><Br/>loremipsum<br/><br/>lorem ipsum<br/><Br/>loremipsum<br/><br/>lorem ipsum<br/><Br/>loremipsum<br/><br/>lorem ipsum<br/><Br/>loremipsum<br/><br/>lorem ipsum<br/><Br/>loremipsum<br/><br/>lorem ipsum<br/><Br/></div>
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
```

Comment: Does not work on Firefox 22.0
Nor does it on IE9.
Problem: Sidebar does not expand, only text does. Also Blue content is not moved to the right, as requested.

Comment: updated answer please check, i have firefox 22.0 its completly working

Comment: What am I doing wrong then? :/ 
This is how it looks after I click on it:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47971103/notworking.png

Comment: here i update my answer and attach firefox-22 screenshot, please check

Comment: well even in the screenshot it is not working... don't you see the scrollbar at the bottom+ the text being cut down on the right side in the sidebar?
Use @AlexThomas solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try **position:fixed** for .sidebar

```
.sidebar {
    background-color: #f12f2f;
    width: 50px;
    position:fixed;
}
```